# Excel formula for entering bi-weekly dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following worksheet:

The grid is filled with the following formula (this example is from cell H4) that populates the grid based on inputs from the table on the left, `=IF($A4="","",IF(AND($E4="Daily",H$2>=$D4,H$2<=$G4),IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="30",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2)&"/",IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="00",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2),$F4)),IF(AND($E4="Weekly",H$2>=$D4,H$2<=$G4,TEXT(H$2,"DDD")=TEXT($D4,"DDD")),IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="30",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2)&"/",IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="00",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2),$F4)),IF(AND($E4="Bi-Weekly",H$2>=$D4,H$2<=$G4,MOD($D4+14,H$2)=0),IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="30",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2)&"/",IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="00",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2),$F4)),IF(AND($E4="Monthly",H$2>=$D4,H$2<=$G4,TEXT(H$2,"MM/DD/YYYY")=CONCATENATE(TEXT(H$2,"MM"),"/",TEXT($D4,"DD"),"/",TEXT($D4,"YYYY"))),IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="30",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2)&"/",IF(RIGHT($F4,2)="00",LEFT($F4,LEN($F4)-2),$F4)),IF(COUNTIF('PowerPoint Gantt'!$A$5:$A$12,$A4)=1,IF(H$2=VLOOKUP($A4,'PowerPoint Gantt'!$A$5:$E$12,5,FALSE)+31,"R",""),""))))))`

The only part of the function that isn't working is the Bi-Weekly selection. I can't figure out how to get recurring entries. I can get the start date and one 14 day period after. I've tried using the `CEILING` function also but still only gets me the next 14th day marked, instead of every 14th day. And ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your rule for Bi-Weekly meetings, it seems that

```
MOD($D4+14,H$2)=0
```

should be replaced with

```
MOD(H$2-$D4,14)=0
```

The latter takes the difference between the starting date and the actual date and checks to see if that can be divided by 14, the number of days in 2 weeks.

Your rule for Weekly meetings could be approached similarly, which seems simpler to me than a rule based on the name of the day, like you are using now.

Comment: That works. And seems like it should also work for weekly, and like you said, be simpler. Thank you for fixing that!